# Passing a variable to another blade php file in a for loop prints only the first entry of the table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-blade

I am working on a project with Laravel and I have the following problem. When I try to pass a variable inside a foreach loop to another blade.php file only prints the first entry of the table.

Code in the main blade.php file:

```
@foreach($policereport as $key => $row)
  <?php $data = $row -> content ?>
  @include('design.textBox')
  @yield('text', $data)
@endforeach
```

Code in the textBox.blade.php file:

```
@section('text')
  <br>
  <div class="text-box">{{ $data }}</div>
@stop
```

I have tried this too but I get the same result:

```
@foreach($policereport as $key => $row)
   @include('design.textBox', ['data' => $row -> content])
   @yield('text')
@endforeach
```

The only thing that helped me iterate through all the content cells in my table is:

```
@foreach($policereport as $key => $row)
    <div class="text-box">{{ $row -> content }}</div>
@endforeach
```

Do I pass the variables wrong to the textBox file? I want to pass it to another file so my code is cleaner as I will have to do the same for more files.

EDIT: Solved my issue by removing the section tag in textBox.blade.php file and the @yield('text') part as recommended in the comments

Comment: I think for your use case you could make a [blade component](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#components) instead

Comment: What's the `@yield('text')` for? Also, if you `@include` a blade file there should be no `@section`s in that file, just the HTML

Comment: @brombeer Thank you very much! This solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

You could use `@each` ([link to documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#rendering-views-for-collections))

```
@each('design.textBox', $policereport, 'data')
```

And in the design.textBox blade:

```
<br>
<div class="text-box">{{ $data }}</div>
```